# chart js linear regression

Tags: deployment, chart.js

I have coding backgrounnd in html, python, and sql. however,I am kind of new to chart js and I am just trying to draw a linear line from the linear regression formula. I was using chatgpt and chart js manual but the trend line (linear regression) does not show up on my website for some reason. does anybody know what is wrong with this set of code?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var data = <?php echo $json\_data; ?>;

var labels = data.map(function (item) {
return item.block3;
});
var values = data.map(function (item) {
return item.block1;
});
var sections = data.map(function (item) {
return item.Section;
});

var uniqueSections = \[...new Set(sections)\];

var datasets = uniqueSections.map(function(section, index) {
var sectionData = data.filter(function(item) {
return item.Section === section;
});
return {
label: section,
data: sectionData.map(function(item) {
return { x: item.block3, y: item.block1 };
}),
backgroundColor: 'rgba(' + (index \* 150) + ', ' + (200 - index \* 200) + ', ' + (index \* 600) + ', 0.5)',
borderColor: 'rgba(' + (index \* 150) + ', ' + (200 - index \* 200) + ', ' + (index \* 600) + ', 1)',
borderWidth: 1,
pointRadius: 7
};
});
```

```
function linearRegression(x, y) {
var n = y.length;

var sum\_x = 0;
var sum\_y = 0;
var sum\_xy = 0;
var sum\_xx = 0;
var sum\_yy = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
sum\_x += x\[i\];
sum\_y += y\[i\];
sum\_xy += x\[i\] \* y\[i\];
sum\_xx += x\[i\] \* x\[i\];
sum\_yy += y\[i\] \* y\[i\];
}
var slope = (n \* sum\_xy - sum\_x \* sum\_y) / (n \* sum\_xx - sum\_x \* sum\_x);
var intercept = (sum\_y - slope \* sum\_x) / n;
var r\_squared = Math.pow((n \* sum\_xy - sum\_x \* sum\_y) / Math.sqrt((n \* sum\_xx - sum\_x \* sum\_x) \* (n \* sum\_yy - sum\_y \* sum\_y)), 2);
return slope, intercept, r\_squared;
}
var regressionData = linearRegression(labels, values);
var slope = regressionData\['labels'\];
var intercept = regressionData\['values'\];
var trendLine = labels.map(function(x) {
return (slope \* x + intercept);
});
datasets.push({
label: 'Trend Line',
data: labels.map(function(x, index) {
return { x: x, y: trendLine\[index\] };
}),
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 0.5)',
borderColor: 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 1)',
borderWidth: 3
});
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'scatter',
data: {
labels: labels,
datasets: datasets
},
options: {
scales: {
x: {
type: 'linear',
position: 'bottom'
}
}
}
});
```

Comment: The function `linearRegression` ends with `return slope, intercept, r\_squared;` which only returns `r_squared`. You probably wanted to have something like `return {slope, intercept, r\_squared};` and then retrieve the values with `slope = regressionData\['slope'\];` and so on. There might be other errors, but the code you posted is not debuggable.

Comment: tried this but it doesn't work. thank you

Comment: I recommend that you take the code from the browser's "view source code", that is the code after php has run, and post it, maybe in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so it can be debugged.

Comment: This is the original code that use for my website. What do you mean by viewing source code?

Comment: Your source code cannot be debugged because it has php in it and missing parts like `$json_data`. You should consider how to make that code debuggable, so that we can copy-paste on our environments and start running it. I suggested one way - to take the generated code *from the browser*.

Comment: I am actually calling this data from my phpadmin. I didn't load the information of the account for the security purpose. I don't think this is the issue of the bug but it is the issue of the syntax or structure of the chart.js code because the website is showing the other data visualizations fine using the code that I wrote. It is just the trendline part. That one linear line doesn't show up.